# Referring to Document Field Value When Setting Another Field in MongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do a query that seems to be basic on the surface. However, I cannot seem to do it efficiently and elegantly. Namely, I have the following document:

```
{
  id:
  runtime: {
    start: Date
    end:  Date
    total: number
  }
  events: [runtime1, runtime2, ...]
}
```

Upon a certain API call, I would like to set the `runtime.end` to the current date and then push what is contained in the runtime object into the events array.

Here is the code I have been trying to use for it:

```
router.get('/stop/:id', function(req,res){
    var collection = db.get('Activity');

    collection.update({
        _id: req.params.id
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "runtime.started": false,
            "runtime.endDate": new Date()
        },
        $push: {events: {
                            startDate: new Date,
                            endDate: new Date
                         }
        }   
    }, 
    function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activity);
    });

});
```

Any idea how this can be done? The code above seem to do nothing, except to edit the `runtime` object.

P.S. I found several questions and answers circa 2010 - 2012 that stated that this could not be done. Have things changed since then?

Comment: Does your code give an error or a different result than expected and if so please specify both of those in detail.

Comment: The code above seem to do nothing, except to edit the `runtime` object. I do not see any errors in the console.

Comment: There's no actual runtime object in the code.

Comment: `$set: {
            "runtime.started": false,
            "runtime.endDate": new Date()
        },`

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks. Is there a workaround you could suggest?

Comment: Like many of those answers show, separately read the doc and then update it.

Answer (score -1):

Check your MongoDB version.  You may need to upgrade to the newest one.  Also, try with the `$push` by itself (without the set, just as in the MongoDB docs example).